# Windows 2008: automated backup of data files

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, automated

Does anyone know how to run an automatic backup of specific directories in Windows 2008? Looking at Windows Server Backup (I guess the "replacement" for NTBackup.exe) it seems like you are only able to backup whole volumns.

TIA.

Karsten

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your backup goal, you might want to take a look at ROBOCOPY.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

I use ROBOCOPY and a Scheduled Task to automatically sync Inetpub from my workstation to a backup directory on the server. The server then writes the backup directory to tape at night.

Answer (score 0):

The change between NTBackup.exe and W2008 Backup utility is major. I suggest you to read this from Microsoft... Which help me to understand those changes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266(WS.10).aspx

Well, finally, I bought ArcServe...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The backup tool (or wbadmin if you install the command line version) only works on complete volumes.

Knowing this in advance, you can plan your volume structure so that data you need to backup is all on a single volume.

I use a scheduled job that backs up across the network (using wbadmin - IIRC, the GUI tools doesn't let you backup to an UNC path, but wbadmin does). The network server that I backup to is a Windows 2003 server with a tape drive, NTBackup makes a tape copy of the backup from the Windows 2008 server. When I retire the 2003 server, it won't be getting replaced by a Windows 2008 server without tape drive support, it will get replaced by a Linux system running samba and another tape drive.

With a bit of thought, you can save yourself the expense of tape backup software for your 2008 servers.